# UNIX_TIMESTAMP field partition for a whole year

Tags: mysql, sql

I am quite new in the subject of partitions and the necessity has arisen due to the great accumulation of data.

Well, basically it is an access control system, there are currently 20 departments and each department has approximately 100 users. The system records the date and time of the entries and exits (from_date / to_date) My intention is to divide by departments and then for a month throughout the year.

**Plan:** 
Partition the table by [ **dep_id** and **date** (from_date and to_date) ]

**Problem** 
I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `employee_id` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `dep_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `index1` (`employee_id`,`from_date`,`to_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have the dates (from_date and to_date) in UNIX_TIMESTAMP format (INT 11)
I am looking to divide it during all the months of the year.
it's possible?

**Mysql - 5.7**

Comment: In theory, it is possible to create partitions, and then subpartitions within each and every partition (the subpartitions must be identical in each partition.)  In practice, subpartitions are a bad idea. I've not run across a use case where subpartitioning was suitable. But maybe your use case is one of the rare birds. You've shown us a plan, but with no rationale for that plan, so I can't in good conscience provide a suggestion regarding subpartitions other than "don't do it".

Comment: Thank you @spencer7593 Well, basically it is an access control system, there are currently 20 departments and each department has approximately 100 users.
The system records the date and time of the entries and exits (from_date / to_date)

My intention is to divide by departments and then for a month throughout the year

Comment: so 20 x 100 = 2,000 users, assuming 100 entrance/exits per day per user, that's 200,000 per day. Times 30 days per month,.. that's 6,000,000 rows per month. (I'm just ballpark guessing at the numbers, you can do the math.)  If the plan is to "age off" the older data, then range partitioning by month would give you the ability to get space back when older partitions are dropped. If that's the plan, I'd keep it simple, and not mess with two levels of partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use range partitioning on an integer column.

Assuming `my_int_col` is unix-style integer seconds since `1970-01-01`

we could achieve monthly partitions with something like this:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (my_int_col)
( PARTITION p20180101 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01 00:00') )
, PARTITION p20180201 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-01 00:00') )
, PARTITION p20180301 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-01 00:00') )
, PARTITION p20180401 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-04-01 00:00') )
, PARTITION p20180501 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-05-01 00:00') )
, PARTITION p20180601 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-06-01 00:00') )
```

Be careful of the time_zone setting of the session. Those date literals will be interpreted as values in the current time_zone... e.g. if you want those to be UTC datetime,  time_zone should be +00:00.

Or, replace the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() expression with a literal integer value... that's what MySQL is going to do with the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() expressions.

Obviously, you can name the partitions whatever you want.

---

Note:  applying partitioning to an existing table will require MySQL to create an entire *copy* of the table, holding an exclusive lock on the original table while the operation completes. So you will need sufficient storage (disk) space, and a window of time for the operation to complete.

It's possible to create a new table that is partitioned, and then copy the older data a chunk at a time. But make the chunks reasonably sized, to avoid ballooning the ibdata1 with large transactions.  And then do some RENAME TABLE statements to move the old table out, and move the new table in.

Some caveats to note with partitioned tables: there's no foreign key support, and there's no guarantee that partitioned table will give better DML performance than a non-partitioned table.

Strategic indexes and carefully planned queries is the key to performance with "very large" tables. And this is true with partitioned tables as well.

Partitioning isn't a magic bullet for performance problems that some novices would like it to be.

As far as creating subpartitions within partitions, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you @spencer7593, I will take your recommendations into consideration.

Comment: There are other partitioning schemes other than RANGE. For example, if the table included an integer column that represented the year and month (all rows in the same month have the same value for that column), then we could implement e.g. LIST partitioning.